# Communication between two AVR microcontrollers over SPI with different power supplies

Tags: power-supply, avr, atmega, spi

I have two ATMEGA32 microcontrollers. First one has the following power supply: 220VAC-line filter-transformer-bridge rectifier-filter-voltage regulator-5VDC. Another one is powered by USB 5VDC. So they have different grounds.

I want to connect them over SPI.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have isolated circuits you can always choose 1 reference point on each circuit to connect to the other. Only one. In most case that will be the grounds.

Both 5 V supplies are isolated from each other through transformers, then you can safely connect their grounds together.

Answer (score 0):

Use a chip like TI's [ISO7241C](http://www.ti.com/product/iso7241c).  Analog Devices has comparable parts and discusses SPI isolation [here](http://ez.analog.com/blogs/engineerzone-spotlight/2011/10/10/fast-spi-connections-through-isolation).

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative, if you need to talk SPI between devices that work on different voltages, is to use a simple level shifter, like the 4050: http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/level_shifters_translators/series/74HC4050.html

Those chips are very cheap, but pay attention when connecting things as they are unidirectional. Depending on the line (MISO, MOSI, SCK, SS, Interrupt), the signals travels from A to B or from B to A.

[image: SPI Data flow]

Comment: A level shifter is likely not going to cut it if you have a non-isolated power supply at a significant offset. If anything, you should recommend an opto-isolator. Additionally, your diagram just shows basic SPI topology, a diagram using your proposed solution would be much more helpful.

Comment: You are right the coment was just about different levels and not isolation. Regarding the diagram I was just illustrating the SPI signal flow direction